# Mysql match words with parentheses boundaries

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+---------------+
| id | duma          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | bbb ccc ddd   |
|  2 | bbb (ccc) ddd |
|  3 | ccc ddd eee   |
|  4 | (ccc) ddd eee |
|  5 | aaa bbb ccc   |
|  6 | aaa bbb (ccc) |
|  7 | bbb(ccc)ddd   |
|  8 | (ccc)dddeee   |
|  9 | aaabbb(ccc)   |
+----+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to match "(ccc)" string as words only, so i'd like to see rows #2, #4 and #6 in the result. I tried theese:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE duma REGEXP '[[:<:]](ccc)[[:>:]]';
+----+---------------+
| id | duma          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | bbb ccc ddd   |
|  2 | bbb (ccc) ddd |
|  3 | ccc ddd eee   |
|  4 | (ccc) ddd eee |
|  5 | aaa bbb ccc   |
|  6 | aaa bbb (ccc) |
|  7 | bbb(ccc)ddd   |
|  8 | (ccc)dddeee   |
|  9 | aaabbb(ccc)   |
+----+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ok, the parentheses is pattern characters, i tried to escape it:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE duma REGEXP '[[:<:]]\\(ccc\\)[[:>:]]';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE duma REGEXP '[[:<:]][(]ccc[)][[:>:]]';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Why not `SELECT * FROM test WHERE duma LIKE '%(ccc)%'` ?

Comment: Sorry, i wrote bad example table data. Now i corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like` with `or` to cover the spaces possibilites you want ...

```
 SELECT * FROM test 
 WHERE duma LIKE '(ccc) %' 
 OR duma LIKE '% (ccc)' 
 OR duma LIKE '% (ccc) %'
```

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of word search you can use like

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE duma like '%(ccc)%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape madness apart, a parenthesis is not a word character so the word boundary marker won't match. From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> ```
> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
> ```
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. **A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_)**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `REGEXP` here, you can simply use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for this comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE duma LIKE '%(ccc)%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP '(^| )[(].*[)]( |$)'
```

This is probably faster than the `OR` of 3 `LIKEs`.

Your definition of "word" is to have a space or beginning/end of string on either side.  That is not the conventional definition, so all the answers given so far (including mine) are not correct with the conventional definition.